# Proving that three functions are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Three functions $f_1,\ f_2\ f_3$ with domain $R$ is linearly dependent if there are three numbers $\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3$ that are not all 0 and $\lambda_1f_1(x)+\lambda_2f_2(x)+\lambda_3f_3(x)=0$ for all x.

Show that $f_1(x)=e^x,\ f_2(x)=e^{2x},\ f_3(x)=e^{3x}$ is linearly independent.

My solution.

$$\begin{cases}\lambda_1e^x+\lambda_2e^{2x}+\lambda_3e^{3x}=0\\
\lambda_1e^0+\lambda_2e^{2\cdot0}+\lambda_3e^{3\cdot0}=0\\
\lambda_1e^{ln2}+\lambda_2e^{2ln2}+\lambda_3e^{3ln2}=0\end{cases}$$

The determinant for the system is
$$\begin{vmatrix}e^x&e^{2x}&e^{3x}\\1&1&1\\2&4&8\end{vmatrix}=0$$
only when $x=ln2\ or\ x=0$, therefor non trivial solutions to the system doesn't exist for all x.

Is this a valid proof and are there clearer ways of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Here is my way of doing it.

Let $$\lambda_1e^x+\lambda_2e^{2x}+\lambda_3e^{3x}=0
.$$ Divide by $e^{3x}$ and let $x \to \infty$ You get $\lambda_3=0$. So $$\lambda_1e^x+\lambda_2e^{2x}=0
.$$ Now divide by $e^{2x}$ and let $x \to \infty$. You get $\lambda_2=0$. Of course, it now follows that $\lambda_1=0$ too.

Comment: That is an interesting way of doing it that I hadn't thought of. The use of limits to prove that for large x $\lambda_3$ must tends towards 0, does that definitely prove that it is in fact 0 and what should I read more of to get a grasp of this concept?

Comment: @ErikEriksson You have $$\lambda_1e^{-2x}+\lambda_2e^{-x}+\lambda_3=0
.$$ after division by $e^{3x}$. So just take limit for each term. The first two terms tend to $0$ and the third term remains $\lambda_3$. So $\lambda_3$ must be $0$.